# Override the default behaviour of GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, ienumerator, callermembername

I have a requirement where I need to know the calling method to the `GetEnumerator()`.

The best way I could think would be possibly overriding the default behaviour to `GetEnumerator` to one that I create i.e `GetEnumerator([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)` but I cannot seem to do this as anything calling it still goes to the original one.

```
public class MyItems : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private List<string> items = new List<string>();
    public MyItems()
    {
        items.Add("One");
        items.Add("Two");
        items.Add("Three");
        items.Add("Four");
        items.Add("Five");
        items.Add("Six");
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
    {
        var method = caller;
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Example of some calling code could be

```
private void button1_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    MyItems items = new MyItems();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {

    }
}
```

The aim is that I would want to know for example `"button1_click"` in the `GetEnumerator()` method

Comment: what does the caller code look like?

Comment: Do not implement IEnumerable directly. Instead, have a method GetEnumerable(string caller) that returns an IEnumerable and take the caller as argument.

Comment: Not implementing IEnumerable is not an option as we are implementing an interface that already implements IEnumerable. The interface is Microsoft IDBSet<T> interface. We need to know the calling method from a generic repositiory so that we can react accordingly but would like to keep the separation between the repository layer and the DBSets etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you want to do, since `foreach`, to my knowledge, always calls the `GetEnumerator()` without any arguments. However, I see two possibilities to your issue

You can use a [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) to get the calling method:

```
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
{
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
    return items.GetEnumerator();
}
```

or you can use another method instead of the `GetEnumerator()` which takes the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Iterate([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(caller);
    return items;
}

foreach (var myItem in items.Iterate())
{
    //..
}
```

Comment: The StackFrame approach works for `foreach()` but do note that in `items.Where(...)` it will give `"Where"` as the caller name.

Comment: @Guillaume do you mean the first method with the `StackTrace`?

Comment: @Default yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

seems like , you need to use StackTrace Class

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        var fr = st.GetFrames();
        if(fr != null && fr.Any() &&fr.Count() >1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fr.ElementAt(1).GetMethod().Name);
        }
```

Comment: doesn't `Any()` imply that there are more than 0 elements? Do you really need to check for `Count` (and if you do, shouldn't it be `>0`)?

Comment: Count() > 1 is used to prevent fr.ElementAt(1) if there is only one frame than it will throw exception

Comment: so then, the `Any()` call is not needed